# MySQL service broker

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

MSSQL Service Broker:  Is there a similar technology in MySQL?

If not, any suggest how to handle async task that can be achieved using Service Broker in MSSQL?

The client side platform is .NET.

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer to this particular question over at: http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

I recommend taking a look at [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). It's a standalone message queue server that implements a "broker" pattern that's extremely similar to SQL Server Service Broker. You can install it on Windows or any Linux. And there is a very decent .NET client library.